# Random Google is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I have the below error when I reload my page several time.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

This is not an error I always get though.

The following is my javascript code:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        var apiKey = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleAPIKey"]';
        var language = $('#Language').text();
        var n = language.indexOf('-');
        language = language.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : language.length);
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.id = "gogapi"
        s.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + apiKey + "&libraries=places&language=" + language + "&callback=initialize";
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        if ($("#Country").val() != '') {
            updateCityLoad($("#Country").val(), "City");
        }
    });


         function updateCityLoad(country, city) {
                getCountryCode(country, function (code) {
                    initialize(code, city)
                });
        }

        function getCountryCode(countryId, callback) {
            var countryCode = "";
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCountryCode", "TestController")' + "&countryId=" + countryId, function (result) {
                countryCode = result.data;
                callback(countryCode);
            });
        }

                function initialize(country, cityID) {
                    var cityfield = document.getElementById(cityID);
                    var options = {
                        types: ['(cities)'],
                        componentRestrictions: { country: country },
                    };
                    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(cityfield, options);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                        $(cityfield).val(place.address_components[0].long_name);
                    })
        }
```

What I am doing is to call the function upDateCity upon change of the country field and upon loading the page, if the country field is not empty, load the google api.  It is when the function updateCityLoad is being called upon the document.ready that I get the google error.

Any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that the script you're trying to reference (googleapi) is not being retrieved in time before `updateCityLoad` is called in your `$(document).ready(){}`.

You can either set a timeout before it is called, render the script in the header tags of your html markup or possibly try call `$(document).ready()` again after the append. Something like...

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var apiKey = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googleAPIKey"]';
    var language = $('#Language').text();
    var n = language.indexOf('-');
    language = language.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : language.length);
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.id = "gogapi"
    s.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + apiKey + "&libraries=places&language=" + language + "&callback=initialize";
    document.head.appendChild(s);

    $(document).ready(function(){//additional call here to wait for document to load
        if ($("#Country").val() != '') {
        updateCityLoad($("#Country").val(), "City");
        }
    });
});
```